# Are selenium 2.16.1 and Firefox 9.0.1 compatible?

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, compatibility

is anyboy running selenium 2.16.1 together with Firefox 9.0.1 and therefore can prove that this versions are working together?

I have problems with not executed commands (timeout and not-found log errrors)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears the answer is both *yes* and *no*:

- *Yes*, on Linux Selenium 2.16.1 and Firefox 9.0.1 get along just fine.
- *No*, on Windows that same combination causes some serious problems; I observe them as well.

On windows I get good results with Selenium 2.16.1 and Firefox 8.0.1, you could try that. Alternatively, try upgrading to Selenium 2.17.0 (released earlier this week).